# Using BeautifulSoup to find a specific value on a website

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, binance

I'm making a discord bot that checks the price of DogeCoin, and for that I decided to use BeautifulSoup to check the price (including the currency, which in this case is EUR) on this website: https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/DOGEEUR/?exchange=BINANCE . The price I want to get is immediately below DOGECOIN/EURO [binance symbol] BINANCE

However I'm new to BeautifulSoup and have very basic knowledge and experience with Python so this is quite a big challenge for me.

Is there a way to store the value of the coin + EUR to a string variable?

I tried using the following code as a reference, but even with tutorials I couldn't get any kind of results.

```py
def get_crypto_price(coin):
    #Get the URL
    url = "https://www.google.com/search?q="+coin+"+price"
    
    #Make a request to the website
    HTML = requests.get(url) 
  
    #Parse the HTML
    soup = BeautifulSoup(HTML.text, 'html.parser') 
  
    #Find the current price 
    #text = soup.find("div", attrs={'class':'BNeawe iBp4i AP7Wnd'}).text
    text = soup.find("div", attrs={'class':'BNeawe iBp4i AP7Wnd'}).find("div", attrs={'class':'BNeawe iBp4i AP7Wnd'}).text

#Return the text 
    return text

#Create a main function to consistently show the price of the cryptocurrency
def main():
  #Set the last price to negative one
  last_price = -1
  #Create an infinite loop to continuously show the price
  while True:
    #Choose the cryptocurrency that you want to get the price of (e.g. bitcoin, litecoin)
    crypto = 'bitcoin' 
    #Get the price of the crypto currency
    price = get_crypto_price()
    #Check if the price changed
    if price != last_price:
      last_price = price #Update the last price
      return price
    time.sleep(3) #Suspend execution for 3 seconds.
```

Comment: The values are dynamically retrieved. You cannot get them from a request to the url you show. Use a dedicated API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There appears to be a public API for prices documented here: `https://github.com/binance/binance-spot-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md#general-api-information`

An example to get a specific item from all (less requests):

```
import requests

def get_price(symbol, prices):
    for price in prices:
        if symbol == price['symbol']:
            return price['price']
        
prices = requests.get('https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price').json()
print(get_price('DOGEEUR', prices))
```

According to the documentation there is a symbol parameter which allows for retrieval of single ticker latest price.

---

Edit: @Mike Malyi rightly points out [if interested in a single item only) -

> Better to add a symbol as a query

```
https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price?symbol=DOGETH
```

> it will save binance weight points, and reduce the size of the
> request.

Comment: Better to add a symbol as a query
```https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price?symbol=DOGETH```
it will save binance weight points, and reduce the size of the request.

Comment: Thanks @MikeMalyi I didn't have time this morning to expand upon my end point about symbol parameter. I have included your really helpful points about weight/size. Thanks again,

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the crypto name while calling the function.

```
crypto = 'bitcoin' 
#Get the price of the crypto currency
price = get_crypto_price(crypto)
```

Please update it is returning the price "32,46,044.24 Indian Rupee"

And because you are comparing it with the number you need to perform operations to get the number from it.

```
price = float(price.replace(",","").split()[0])
```

This will return you the price in number : 3255838.53

Comment: You're not really answering my question, I understand what you mean and your instructions, but I want the price of Dogecoin from the website I refered on my question, not about the piece of code I put in there